# Images not loading online but works when I try it offline (local), why is this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, local-storage

I am using localgetstorage and setstorage to load a list of links and show them as in a slideshow. The problem is that when I preview it on my PC it works, as soon as I try to use the page in my server online it won't work. Have I done something wrong?

Here's a link:

http://hem.bredband.net/noor/bildspelet/bildspelet.html

It is very buggy and I'd rather just use a thirdparty slideshow plugin but I don't know where to find one that matches my needs and is free..

Comment: Are you trying to do things with different domains or sub-domains?  Sometimes what works locally due to browser permissions suddenly won't work due to cross-domain concerns online.

Comment: No this is basically just pulling in a list and showing them to you.. or maybe, i'm trying to pull in images from my harddrive, but this shouldn't stop it from working as it did a few versions ago.. almost identical, all i've done since then is centerize everything and a few lines of css.. i think

Comment: You'd know for sure if you were using version control. Use Subversion, Git, or Mercurial and never look back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you reference the images in the right way? If I take a look at the source of your provided Link, I see references to your c:-Drive:

```
<b>C:\Users\Admin\Pictures\IMG_0005.JPG<br>
C:\Users\Admin\Pictures\IMG_0631.JPG<br>
C:\Users\Admin\Pictures\IMG_0322.JPG</b><br>
```

I know, in this case it's just plain text, but if you reference the images in the same way, it would explain your problems...

Comment: Hm...maybe a prefix with file:// would help out.

Comment: even with a file:// you would run into problems. file:// is a security risk and hence this protocol will only work for trusted (local) domains. And the pictures would also only be locally visible - is that what Noor wants?

Comment: @Ralf - Considering the comment that he wants to pull images from the hard drive above, sounds plausible.

Comment: @justkt- yes, but why put the html on a server in this case?

Comment: @Ralf - Sorry for being afk, you are correct, the only thing I want to do is make the pictures be locally visible, the reason is that I'm trying to make a screenshow. I want my site to be your start page and when you're afk  for a while and you've left the browser window open you'll see the slideshow, just like a screensaver works.. I think I should try to find a plugin that allready does that maybe, I just don't like giving up!

Comment: @Noor - ok. as a "screensaver" it could make sense. But I guess you should use another source for the pictures (maybe flickr?) which is accessible for all of your users.
A normal website is not allowed to reference local files - already the check for existence can be enough to attack a system. So in order to make your page work, you have set it as trusted site in your browser. Will your users do that? The whole site will be trusted and hence has special permissions...

Answer (score 3):

You can't read a local file in your HTML page unless you use the [FileAPI](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/) (using a fileReader)
But it is only implemented in firefox 3.6+ yet. May be it will be also in chrome 5.0

Here are [some articles on this subject](http://hacks.mozilla.org/category/fileapi/) and [a demo](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/12/firefox-36-fileapi-demo-reading-exif-data-from-a-local-jpeg-file/)

You can also use [OfflineAPI](http://hacks.mozilla.org/category/offline/) to store information about the file selection and [DragDrop](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/12/file-drag-and-drop-in-firefox-3-6/) to extend user experience

Comment: I'm really doubting your answer allthough I'll accept it. I'm only doubting for one reason which is that I think I got it working, I might be wrong.. don't think so but for now I'll go with it. Thanks!

Comment: Excuse me I was not very clear. When you load your HTML page from your computer (with file:///path-to-your-html-file), you can see pictures from your local computer. But when you load your HTML page from a server using http:, you change the protocol (from file: to http:) and security constraint don't allow you to see the content of file using the protocol file:. To bypass these constraint you should use HTML5 APIs, but it is not yet implemented in browsers except Firefox 3.6+.

Comment: You can find some explications on how to use the file API in this article : http://www.incaseofstairs.com/2010/05/border-image-generator-local-file-access/

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar problem. On localhost (XAMPP) i had the following.

```
    <img src="images/table1.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: auto;" alt = ""/>
```

for some reasons my local server overlooked that the actual name of the image was table1.JPG, but the online server couldnot pick the extension in small caps.

```
    <img src="images/table1.JPG" style="width: 100%; height: auto;" alt = ""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your permission status code for your images in your server, i think it should be 0664 and not 0660

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).